# Interop Excel - How to set the excel file to allways open at the last row?

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-interop

I`m populating an excel worksheet with data every day (using Interop.Excel). After the data was inserted, a user will open the excel normally. What I want is that at open, the excel file to be scrolled at the last row inserted, or at a specific row. This is what i tried, but had no effect.

```
if (position == mTables.Count - 1)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range activeCell = excelWorksheet.Cells[decalajMesaje, 1];
            activeCell.Select();
            activeCell.Activate();

            excelWorkbook.Worksheets[1].Cells[decalajMesaje, 1].Select();
            excelWorkbook.Worksheets[1].Cells[decalajMesaje, 1].Activate();

            excelWorkbook.Save();
        }
```

Any idea what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you could use this formula in C# to find the last row used in worksheet:

```
int lastUsedRow = excelWorkbook.Worksheets[1].Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                     System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                     XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                     false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
```